# Textarea not showing in django User change form

Tags: python, html, css, django, django-templates

I have a django app with the user creation form having a textarea for input. This part is working fine. But the **user change form** is outputting the **textarea** as a simple regular **input field** as well.
Following is the code for user change form

```
              <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
              <div class="form-group">
                <strong><label class="control-label" for="town-city">About Me</label></strong>
                {{form.bio|add_class:"form-control"}}
                  {% if form.bio.value == None %}
                    <strong style="color:red;">{{form.bio.errors}}Empty field</strong>
                  {% endif %}
                  <strong style="color:red;">{{form.bio.errors}}</strong>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add a textarea [widget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/widgets/) to your field:
`textarea_field = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)`

Comment: I've written this in the user sign up form and it does show up there, but it shows up as simple input field i.e. one row in the user change form

Comment: If you inspect element in your browser do you see it as an input or textarea? If input then your widget isn’t properly set. If textarea, just add extra rows.

Comment: Thank you for the help man. Actually what I copied the entire input element from the dev tools' inspect. And changed the input tag to <textarea> and placed the value from the database between the <textarea>here</textarea>